# Does jsp:setProperty escape esc-sequences?

Tags: java, jsp

I use `jsp:setProperty` to fill in bean fields with user data. My `JSP` page looks like:

```
<%-- skipped code --%>
<jsp:setProperty name="myBean" property="*"/>
<%-- skipped code --%>
<input type="text" name="myField" value=""></td> 
<%-- skipped code --%>
```

When I specify in text field value containing esc-sequences (e.g. `\r\n`) and then try to debug `setMyField(String s)` setter in my bean, `s` appears to come with escaped characters (e.g. `\\r\\n`).

Is it common `jsp:setProperty` behavior? I tried to find information about this feature but unsuccessfully. I need documentation or any another proof that it supposed to work such way.

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: @summerbulb, Oracle WebLogic Server 10.3.4. Does it matter? :)

Comment: Well, the jsp implementation of the jsp tag is in the sever code, isn't it? :)

Comment: Are you getting the same results for jsp:setProperty and setMyName()? (i.e. does getMyName() give the same result if called after both?)

Comment: @summerbulb, are you mean setting property manually by calling `setMyField(String s)` in jsp?

Comment: Yes. I have a feeling this behavior has to do with the bean, rather than the jsp tag.

Comment: @summerbulb, I've just tried to set property manually by calling setter `<% myBean.setMyField("\n"); %>` from jsp and, as expected, value came unescaped. I believe that exactly tag escapes sequences.

Comment: I did some major digging and could not find any documentation on the escaping behavior. The closest thing I could find was [this](http://oreilly.com/catalog/jserverpages/chapter/ch05.html) O'reilley book chapter (see 'Formatting HTML Output'), talking about quotes in input fields.

Comment: @summerbulb, as far as I see it is not what I'm looking for. It's about generation html page and escaping html special characters with their codes. Thank you for help attempt anyway!

Comment: Could you please share the generated servlet code of this jsp?

Comment: @ShashiBhushan, sorry I could not, but I sure that you'll not find there anything specific to mine application

Answer (score 0):

When you say `s` appears to come with escaped characters (e.g. `\\r\\n`), this is the behavior of debugger. There are actually four characters: `'\\', 'r', '\\', 'n'`.

If you print it out through `System.out.println(myBean.getMyField())`, you should see `\r\n` in the console.

When you do `myBean.setMyField("\n")`, actually there's only one character: `'\n'`.

Comment: So if I add sysout to setter method it will print `\r\n` as carriage return + line feed characters? I have no access to workstation now so I could not verify this behavior.

Comment: It won't. You need to convert them by yourself if you need that behavior.

Comment: do you mean that there is no difference between debugging and usual mode?

Comment: correct. setProperty would not process the escape character specially.

Comment: Could you please provide proofs from the official resources that `setProperty` does not process the escape character specially? This is what I'm need.

Comment: `jsp:setProperty` is described in jsp specification. You can download it here: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsp-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/  It doesn't mention it will process the escape character specially.

Comment: @zvdh: Changgeng is right, its to debugger's behaviour to show the escape charachters like this. So probably you may want to read the debuggers documentation for how it deals with these escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the input field is being sanitized (by something else in your application).

As a general rule escape sequences

```
\r
\n
```

need to be escaped (for security reasons) when they come in via input field. This would mean adding an additional backslash to these sequences before the input is processed by the server.

I suggest replacing the sequences before 'submission' with something like

```
<br>
```

Sorry, I cant provide you official documentation that states the jsp tag isn't doing this.

Comment: Do you have any idea how could this escaping in my app be performed? Is there common way to extend jsp tags or something like this?

Comment: JSP is server side, input is client side. I Dont think that the JSP is doing this escaping.

When the user hits "submit" the input is then sent back to the server and used in the JSP (the response from the Server). Before that input ever gets to the JSP it would already need to be sanitized (by a javascript function, for example)

Comment: Escaping is performed at the server side.

Comment: Between the input submit and the resulting JSP something is modifying the String. If aren't doing something client-side then maybe your servlet container has a filter setup for all input form submissions and it's causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Changgeng partially.

the behavior you are seeing is the debugger itself, so don't worry. I think it tried to preserve all the characters you sent and you must know the complete value so it appends one more `\` to each `\` in the sequence.

It doesn't want you to be confused `'\n'` with the `new line`, so he preserves everything.

If you print it on console, it will be the same sequence you sent from client side.